# How can I know if an entry is selected or focused in GTK for C?

Tags: c, gtk

I have two entries and I need to know which one is selected. Depending on that function, a button will set text to the entry selected.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [gtk_widget_is_focus](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-is-focus). That returns true if typing on the keyboard would send text to that widget.